# Live video stream on website

Tags: javascript, html, live, broadcast

Hey Guys i have to integrate a live video capturing on a HTML/JavaScript site for a presentation. But i dont really know what i have to search for. Please give me a hint. :)

The video will be recorded live from a camera man who interview someone. In the Background is a template (HTML/JavaScript) which contains a lot of information to the current topic and **also the live broadcast**! Everything on thesame site.

Is this possible and if yes how? I dont know what i have to search for in the internet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the Flash Media Server is hat you need. There are also many other alternative Products oon the market, like the Red5 Media Server which is open source.